# Magento use simple product price instead of Super Attribute price

Tags: magento, configuration, attributes, super

I have a Configurable Product with a Super Attribute and a number of Simple Products (with different prices). In Admin when i select the Configurable Product >> Associated Products I can see the simple products. On the front-end when I try to add one of these simple products to the basket instead of seeing the price of that simple product i am seeing the price of the Configurable Product + the values in the Super Attribute Configuration for the selected product. Does anyone know how to change this so that the simple product price is used?

Comment: Is anyone able to answer this or have i reached a dead end

Comment: you must set the difference in product options somewhere in "Associated product" in configurable product. Then register attribute configuration for price and enter difference in the price. This is how I handled it.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with exact same issue a couple years ago and Magento EE support could not provide much help.  Client has an ERP system that only contains simple products.  So configurable products are only for creating shopping experience in Magento.  This makes ignoring simple product pricing for a base+offset configurable pricing model in Magento a problem.  Never able to understand the logic to ignoring available pricing data for an additional meta pricing model!?

Magento EE support unofficially pointed me to a third party extension. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html  This extension is no longer supported so core upgrades have required work to keep things working.  Looks like there are other extensions addressing this issue that may offer support.

I wanted to believe someone smarter than I could explain a better approach to solving this problem.